# How to convert my sql query to laravel ORM

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm new in laravel 5 how can i convert this query to laravel ORM

```
select m.nombre,c.fecha_control as primer_control,
(select control.fecha_control 
  from control 
  where m.id = control.id_mascota
  order by control.fecha_control 
  DESC limit 1) as ultimo_control
from mascota m
left join control as c on m.id = c.id_mascota
GROUP BY m.nombre
```

i try this but it didn't work...

```
 DB::table('mascota as m')
        ->leftJoin('control as c','m.id','=','c.id_mascota')
        ->select('m.nombre','c.fecha_control as primer_control',
            \DB::raw('select control.fecha_control  from control 
                        where m.id = control.id_mascota
                        order by control.fecha_control 
                        DESC limit 1
                        ) as ultimo_control'))
        ->groupBy('m.id');
```

Thanks

Comment: Consider learning Eloquent relationships first. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only had syntax errors, it works fine. it take me  3 hours to realize

```
DB::table("mascota as m")
 ->leftJoin('control as c','m.id','=','c.id_mascota')
 ->select('m.nombre','c.fecha_control as primer_control'),
    DB::raw("(select control.fecha_control 
              from control 
              where m.id = control.id_mascota
              order by control.fecha_control 
              DESC limit 1) as ult_control"))
  ->groupBy('m.id');
```